# SQL : finding people that have made more than one order within a 30 day period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a (simplified) table called Orders that has the following columns:

```
OrderId,
PersonId
OrderDate
```

What I am trying to find out is how many people in the table have made more than one order within a 30 day period.  For example, if Bob orders something on Januay 3, 2015 and then orders another something on January 21, 2015, he would be included in the list because he ordered two things within a 30 day period.

I have been trying to put together the SQL statements to do this, but I am not very good at this and can't seem to figure it out.

I am using SQL Server.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you only looking for a fixed 30-day period, or for example, over an entire year, did anyone order within 30 days of another?

Comment: Sorry, probably should have specified.  Looking for the entire year.

Comment: Then my answer should do exactly what you want, just update WHERE clause for the year range you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You COULD try by doing with a join to the table itself based on same customer and order date within 30 of the order being compared to...

I would ensure to have TWO indexes on the table... 
First by date for the range you may be expecting (OrderDate)
Second based on ( PersonID, OrderID, OrderDate ) to get them sequential for a given person for the join basis.

```
select
      O.PersonID,
      O.OrderDate,
      O.OrderID,
      MAX( O2.OrderDate ) as LastOrderDate,
      COUNT(*) as TotalOrders
   from
      Orders O
         JOIN Orders O2
            on O.PersonID = O2.PersonID
           AND O.OrderID < O2.OrderID
           AND O2.OrderDate < DATEADD( day, 30, O.OrderDate);
   where
      O.OrderDate > '2014-01-01'
   group by
      O.PersonID,
      O.OrderDate,
      O.OrderID
```

Now, because this is a JOIN (not a left-join), it is guaranteeing another order exists for the same person but a higher order than the one based on the main query "O" alias, but ONLY within 30 days of the original O.OrderDate.

Now, this may create multiple instances for a single person, such as an example where person buys on Jan 1, Jan 20, Jan 29, Feb 1, Feb 10, May 4 because

From the original order Jan 1, that will encompass a count of 3 entries ending at Jan 29.

But now, the outer cycle gets to the Jan 20 record and it finds 3 entries after it up to and including Feb 10... Same person, but the rolling 30 days.

Similar for Jan 29, then Feb 1, but will not have an entry for Feb 10 as nothing after it within 30 days until the May 4th date, and nothing for May 4th as nothing after it period.

Now, if you only care about the WHO, once you've confirmed the above query WOULD work, you MAY only want those with the total orders MORE than 2... say 3 or more within 45 days?  Who knows.. Just add a HAVING COUNT(*) > 2.

That should still work, but now, getting just the person... Ignore the rest of the columns and just do

```
Select distinct O.PersonID from ... rest of query
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for not only giving the answer, but also for providing an explanation so that I can understand how this works.

Comment: @meyousikmann, no problem.  I prefer to give explanations than just a SQL answer... if you understand the mechanics behind it, you can apply similar approach to other future queries...  This way more people can read and.... OOhhhh, I get it now... moments.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select PersonId, count(PersonId)
from Orders 
where OrderDate <= '2015-01-31' and OrderDate >= '2015-01-01' 
group by PersonId 
having count(PersonId) > 1
```

Comment: This is not what they are looking for... Not just a count within 30 days, but over a year's time, any order that is within 30 days of another... such as Mar 15, 2014 to April 7, 2014 would qualify for being within 30 days of each other.